# google chrome doesn't executes all javascript statements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i have a function `initView()` which initializes all values, so that my HTML page looks as it should look.

in firefox, IE!! and opera is all working fine, but in google chrome, when i make the browser window smaller and then against big, chrome seems to be a bit lazy and don't renders all as he should do. 
the problem is that i can't even check whats wrong, because if i want to open the webinspector, suddenly everything is rendered fine again.

what can i do to avoid this?

the initView function looks something like this. nothing special just some style manipulations (about 50).

```
var initView = function(){
    $(element).css('left','50px').height('300px');
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code or link to an example?

Comment: some page loading events have very limited capabilities to prevent popups and all kinds of badness.

Comment: and what can you do to against this limitations

Comment: If it were a security limitation, you could try running chrome with `--disable-web-security` (if on windows, easiest way to do this is at the end of a shortcut), but my guess is that this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this could be the answer, but jQuery's height() function takes an integer value and assumes that you are giving a value in pixels.

Maybe the other browsers are interpreting your .height('300px') as you want and chrome is working correctly